# Searching for a expression of a dampening function

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am looking for a function $f(x)$ where

- $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$
- $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$
- $f'(x)=1$ for $x=0$, where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ (about this I am not adamant)
- I don't care about $x<0$
- $f$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$
- $f$ is completely differentiable everywhere for $x>0$
- $f(x)<x$ for $x>0$

I would prefer a function closely related to a logarithmic function.

I want to use the function to make a positive parameter smaller, to give it sort of a constraint.

Comment: $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ for $x \rightarrow 0$ and $f(x) < x$ for $x > 0$ pretty much contradict each other, I think? If the first holds then $f(x_{small})$ will be huge, so $f(x_{small}) \gg x_{small}$.

Comment: @SampleTime: Sorry, I misswrote.

Answer (score 0):

*I got the idea, just after posting the question, but it might be useful for someone else later on, so I am posting it.*

---

The answer is, to simply use the shifted logarithm and divide it by the derivative of the original logarithm , so that the derivative becomes 1 for $x=0$:

$f(x) = log_b(x+1) \cdot ln(b) = ln(x+1)$

Comment: That's the same thing as ln(x+1).

Comment: @Acccumulation: True story. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest would be the square root function. If you want a logarithmic function, then ln(1+x) works. If you to get fancy, you could do the sigmoid function with the appropriate translation.

Comment: Square root does not work because of the last condition. However I like the idea with the sigmoid. It does violate the first condition, but it is a nice alternative if I want a real upper boundary.